# SQL 2005 nvarchar(max) problem

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, nvarchar

I have the following in a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @TSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @TSQL = N'.....' Which contains about 33000 characters of text
```

When I do a `PRINT LEN(@TSQL) 7968` is returned. Why is the rest of @TSQL cut off?

Comment: You seem to be missing the variable name in your `DECLARE`.

Comment: Yes, youre right, I added it.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that when you concatenate everything is a nvarchar(max)

take a look at this

```
DECLARE @n NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @n = REPLICATE(convert(varchar(max),'A'),300000)

select LEN(@n), DATALENGTH(@n)
GO
```

--300000    600000

```
DECLARE @n NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @n = REPLICATE('A',300000)

select LEN(@n), DATALENGTH(@n)
```

--8000  16000